# Llamar elementos de un div con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Tengo una seccion que esta oculta pero al dar click al boton no funciona la verdad no se casi nada de javascript pero no ser burlen por favor.

Mi css

```
    .cal{display:none;}
    .calculadora{width:95%;text-align:center;}
    .calculadora a{width:60%;padding:8px 0px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;background:#222;color:#DDD;display:block;margin-top:5px;border:solid 1px #000;border-radius:8px;font-size:16px;font-family:arial, sans;box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);}
    .calculadora a:hover{width:65%;padding:10px 0px;background:#000;color:#00FF99;font-size:18px;}
```

El intento de javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calcular(){
    var calcular = document.getElementById("cal")
    calcular[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    </script>
```

Y el html

```
    <div class="calculadora">
    <a onclick="calcular()" ><strong>Comprueba Tu Talla</strong></a>
    <section class="cal" id="cal">
    <br><h3>¿Cómo Saber Tu Talla Exacta?</h3><br>
```

Sopongo el problema es el javascript ya que se que soy pesimo, agradeceria mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola de nuevo amigo pues si evidentemente es el javascript el problema ya que no es necesario crear variables ni nada es ese caso por lo que veo en tu código puedes usar el siguiente javascript

```
        function calcular(){
                 document.getElementById("cal").style.display = "block";
        }
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Si me imaginaba que era el javascript verificare con el tuyo y perdon por preguntar tanto :v.

Comment: No pidas perdón la verdad todos hemos sido nuevos y es normal tener dudas recuerda estamos aca para ayudar y mejorar y a como comento un miembro en tu pregunta anterior y ver esta pregunta se ve la mejora asi que no hay problema y suerte amigo.

Comment: Si funciono perfecto muchisimas gracias :).